# GoLang : "No common algorithm for key exchange" error

Tags: go, ssh

I am new to GoLang and I am trying to connect to a remote server using go. But I keep getting the following error

```
Failed to dial: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange; client offered: [curve2****-sh****@libssh.org ****-sha*-nis****ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp**** diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 diffie-hellman-group1-sha1], server offered: [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha***]
```

below is the config that I use to connect

```
 config := &ssh.ClientConfig{

    User: user,

    HostKeyCallback: nil,

    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{

    publicKey,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, like the error says, the client and the server don't have any algorithms they're willing to agree on, so they can't talk. The six that Go is offering are all the ones it supports (out of the 12 that openssh does); the server is only offering *one* that isn't any of those. Your options:

1. Convince the server to accept more KEX algorithms; it's possible that it supports more, and someone just configured it super restrictively.
2. Implement [DH Group Exchange](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4419.txt) for x/crypto/ssh yourself, and send the patch upstream.
3. Find a different client.

Comment: If possible could you tell me how to do any/each of those ? I am very new to golang and network programming and I'd appreciate any help. Thank YOU

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459755/error-while-trying-to-connect-via-ssh-to-remote-host/58461799#58461799)

I'm still working on that but [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58460545/1256452) put some interesting tips in order to resolve it.

hope it helps.