# Error while trying to connect via SSH to remote host

Tags: go, encryption, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote host to issue a command, but I'm getting the following error message while running the code:

> ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange; client offered: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org ecdh-sha2-nistp256 ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp521 diffie-hellman-group14-sha1], server offered: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x759836]

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
func (SSHClient *SSH) Connect(mode int) {
    var SSHConfig *ssh.ClientConfig
    var auth []ssh.AuthMethod

    if mode == CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_FILE {
        auth = []ssh.AuthMethod{SSHClient.readPublicKeyFile(SSHClient.Cert)}
    }

    SSHConfig = &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            SSHClient.User,
        Auth:            auth,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         time.Second * DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
    }

    SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers, "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", SSHClient.IP, SSHClient.Port), SSHConfig)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR - While trying to Dial to the host %s with error: %s", SSHClient.IP, err.Error())
        return
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR - While trying to create a new session on host %s with error: %s", SSHClient.IP, err.Error())
        client.Close()
        return
    }

    SSHClient.session = session
    SSHClient.client = client
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error, it looks like a cipher mismatch i.e. `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` vs `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`. I'm not sure why you're getting that `panic` there despite the fact that all the errors are already handled.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a SSH question that has to do with programming and development.

Comment: @happugopher is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is.... the server is only willing to talk over diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

And:

- [golang/go issue 2903](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2903): ssh: add diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, has been closed 6 days ago
- [golang/go/issue 17230](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17230): proposal: `x/crypto/ssh`: support Diffie-Hellman Group Exchange from RFC 4419, is being implemented now.

So you would need for your client a fork of  `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`, like [bored-engineer/ssh](https://github.com/bored-engineer/ssh/), where [commit 39a91b](https://github.com/bored-engineer/ssh/commit/39a91b2f99659c746b120025dff1a4fb46b380b7) and [commit fe5e4ff](https://github.com/bored-engineer/ssh/commit/fe5e4ff9a3592bf7c231b4ed160298c8c4a04c57) does add support for diffie-hellman-group1-sha1.
Or install the latest of [`golang/crypto`](https://github.com/golang/crypto), which includes [commit 57b3e21](https://github.com/golang/crypto/commit/57b3e21c3d5606066a87e63cfe07ec6b9f0db000).

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC, I will install the latest golang/crypto and see if this issue is solved, I will post and update tomorrow, hopefully with some good news! :)

Comment: after updating to the latest ```golang/crytpo``` I'm still getting the ```ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange```, maybe do I need to change something else from the code?

Comment: @happygopher What version of Go are you using?

Comment: I'm using ```go version go1.11 linux/amd64```

Comment: @happygopher Can you try with Go 1.13.3?

Comment: I also try with version ```go version go1.13.1 linux/amd64``` and I get the same error msg

Comment: @happygopher OK. Just checking. I was reading on a similar topic: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoTLSNoStringIssue

Comment: I just update to version ```go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64```, and still got the same error:

Comment: ```ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange; client offered: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org ecdh-sha2-nistp256 ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp521 diffie-hellman-group14-sha1], server offered: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x7a4fb6]```

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: @Sreenath I don't know: you should leave a comment/question under the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

The panic is somewhat strange.  Clearly something goes wrong when no key exchange algorithm can be agreed-to.  As [VonC notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58460545/1256452), Diffie-Hellman *key exchange* was only added fairly recently (June 3).  Since your server offers only that algorithm, you can't get started without it.

This is not the cause of the panic (which seems to happen inside `ssh.Dial` itself), but I will note that when you do this:

> ```
> SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers, "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")
> ```

you wind up telling the Go code to *only* use diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 as the channel encryption.  You do not *add* to anything here.  The reason is that `SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers` is initially nil.  So you might as well write:

```
SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers = []string{"diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"}
```

to get the same effect, which is: things won't work.

You can call [`SetDefaults`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Config.SetDefaults) so that the list is non-empty before adding to the list, but adding to the list is ineffective if there is no implementation for this mode—and even with the new commits, Diffie-Hellman isn't allowed for anything other than the key exchange itself.  Note that `ssh.Dial` calls `ssh.NewClientConn`, which is [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/87dc89f01550277dc22b74ffcf4cd89fa2f40f4c/ssh/client.go#L71-L89) and which starts with:

```
fullConf := *config
fullConf.SetDefaults()
```

`SetDefaults` in turn is [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/87dc89f01550277dc22b74ffcf4cd89fa2f40f4c/ssh/common.go#L237-L272) and contains:

```
if c.Ciphers == nil {
    c.Ciphers = preferredCiphers
}
var ciphers []string
for _, c := range c.Ciphers {
    if cipherModes[c] != nil {
        // reject the cipher if we have no cipherModes definition
        ciphers = append(ciphers, c)
    }
}
c.Ciphers = ciphers
```

which first says that if the config's `Ciphers` is not set, it should use the defaults, and then immediately after that, *filters away* any string that's not in `cipherModes`.  This in turn is defined [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/87dc89f01550277dc22b74ffcf4cd89fa2f40f4c/ssh/cipher.go#L97-L132) and starts with this comment:

```
// cipherModes documents properties of supported ciphers. Ciphers not included
// are not supported and will not be negotiated, even if explicitly requested in
// ClientConfig.Crypto.Ciphers.
```

This phrase is not in the documentation.  It should be!  **Ciphers not included are not supported and will not be negotiated, even if explicitly requested in `ClientConfig.Crypto.Ciphers`.**

(See the last link above for the set of ciphers that *are* supported.  Note that this list has grown over time.)

Comment: Hi Torek, thanks for your response and explanation, like I said i will try VonC response about install the latest golang/crypto and see if that solves my problem, will post and update tomorrow. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 2):

Diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 is a key exchange algorithm. Should be KeyExchanges instead of Ciphers in the Config struct

```
SSHConfig.Config.KeyExchanges = append(SSHConfig.Config.KeyExchanges, "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")
```

Instead of

```
SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(SSHConfig.Config.Ciphers, "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")
```

If KeyExchanges is not specified, the default algorithms used can be found in ssh/common.go

```
// preferredKexAlgos specifies the default preference for key-exchange algorithms
// in preference order.
var preferredKexAlgos = []string{
    kexAlgoCurve25519SHA256,
    kexAlgoECDH256, kexAlgoECDH384, kexAlgoECDH521,
    kexAlgoDH14SHA1,
}
```

As you can see, kexAlgoDH1SHA1 or diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 is not listed at this time